# Exclude dictionary in Mac Word 2011

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, dictionary

I'm having trouble adding an exclude dictionary in Word 2011 on a Mac. I'm following the steps on Microsoft's user forum [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-exclude-words-from-words-dictionary-on/3b9ae9da-49c6-412f-90d1-b30769806b27).

I have created an exclude dictionary, saved it and reverted the default preference to save future docs as a .docx. But I am having trouble with Step 5--add the exclusion dictionary. Under *Preferences* → *Spell & Grammar* → *Dictionaries* → *Add*, the .dic exclude dictionary is greyed out and cannot be added or selected.

Also, the directions in the Microsoft forum suggest downloading TextWrangler to enable the exclude dictionary. Is this still the best way to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Jill, not sure if this will help you, but if you know someone with a PC (or a more recent version of Word on the Mac), get them to create an exclude dictionary on their version of Word and to email it to you. You can then save the file where you keep the other custom dictionaries for Word. It's the only way I have been able to get a working exclude dictionary for Word 2011 on my Mac. Also, I cannot make changes to my exclude dictionary and ask people to update the file for me and email me the new one as needed. Natalie